# Cannot edit a .java file with a java program

Tags: java, string, file, replace, edit

I am a beginner in java. Ihave a string replacement code in which the user specifies the file path, the string to replace and the string to replace with. The code just works fine with .txt or .in files. But when I try to edit a .java file for which I intended to write the code, it somehow is unable to edit it. Can anybody suggest where actually the problem is? My code goes as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class StringReplace{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Enter path of file:");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String path=sc.nextLine();
        File f=new File(path);
        if (f.canRead())
        {
            System.out.print("Now enter the string to replace:_");
            String oldString=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Now enter the string to replace with:_");
            String newString=sc.nextLine();
            StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
            sc=new Scanner(f);
            sc.useDelimiter("");
            while(sc.hasNext())
            {
                sb.append(sc.next());
            }
            sc.close();
            FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(path);
            PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(fw,true);
            System.out.println(sb);
            pw.println(sb.toString().replaceAll(oldString, newString));
            fw.close();
            pw.close();
            System.out.print("DONE!");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("File Does Not Exist");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well what *do* it do? I wouldn't use `Scanner` for this, to be honest - I'd use `BufferedReader` and just read a line at a time, probably writing as I went.

Comment: Who knows what actual problem is working with binary or text stream. Java file may contain unicode chars.

Comment: For me Code works fine in .java file also.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I am using scanner here with a blank string as delimiter since I need to preserve the all default delimiters of scanner and bufferedReader in the edited file. Only "oldString"s will be changed.

Comment: What is the error you get exactly ?

Comment: No error really. The code runs error less. But when the input file has a .java extension, I find no change to the file after code execution.

Comment: In this case, could you give some kind of sample input which is failing ? Because there should be no difference between a `.txt` and a `.java` file, they are both plain text files after all.

Comment: I would use perl pie [ http://technosophos.com/node/69]  for this kind of string replacement.

Comment: don't know what happened yesterday, but the code seems to work fine now. Sorry to bother you guys.

Comment: @JonSkeet, what exactly is the concern with Scanner?

Comment: @VictorMukherjee your code works fine in .java files also. The file contents are changed as expected.

Comment: @dimo414: Scanner is usually aimed for reading a *token* at a time. It's not *obvious* to me what happens when you set the delimiter as "" - maybe it does something appropriate, maybe not. But using `BufferedReader.readLine` says *exactly* what it does.

Comment: I tried to use nextLine method of Scanner and then append a new line to the StringBuffer object for every single run of the loop, but when I write it back to the file, those appended lines were missing. So I used the "" delimiter.

Comment: @JonSkeet gotcha, that makes sense.  Not sure what your (@Victor) issue with Scanner's `nextLine()` was, but I'd agree with Jon, using the undocumented behavior of the `""` delimiter isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments state, there should be no difference between a ".java" file and any other text file.

I suspect that the problem is that you haven't realized that your editor application is actually coded to do a **regular expression** search / replace, not a simple string search / replace.   (That is what `String.replaceAll(...)` does ...)  If unwittingly supply a "string to replace" that contains regex metacharacters, you may find that it doesn't match or that it matches in a place that you are not expecting.